AWS allow creating Route53 records with permissions policy cross account
I'm trying to figure out a way to have a role that allows organization accounts to create a record, which have to contain their account id, in a hostedzone owned by a different account
like so service-a.ACCOUNT_ID.shareddomain.tld
I know there are ways to get the account in the policy itself, but is it possible to connect it with the create recordset permissions to only allow that kind of pattern
And avoiding "faking" records like this like so service-a.OTHER_ACCOUNT_ID.shareddomain.tld from ACCOUNT_ID

Have you had a look at the AWS SCP? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps_examples.html
You can have something like this
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "route53:ChangeResourceRecordSets"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:route53:::hostedzone/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "route53:ChangeBatchRecordNames": [
            "*<AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>*"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

